# Create nxn matrix

Tags: r, matrix

For example, if the user entered 5, the matrix will be like fpllowing:

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4,5,6
3,4,5,6,7
4,5,6,7,8
5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/matrix

Comment: How is this related to MATLAB? Please don’t tag-spam! Also read [ask] to create a better question that is more likely to get answered.

Comment: You need it interactive?

Comment: thank you for editing my question, what do you mean by interactive @DavidArenburg, sorry Cris

Comment: You said "if the user entered"- does it mean you are building some interface that expects and input from a user in real time?

Comment: no need for interface I mean I just get an input and print matrix on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply`

```
n <- 5
sapply(seq_len(n), `+`, seq_len(n) -1)
```

-output

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    6
#[3,]    3    4    5    6    7
#[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
#[5,]    5    6    7    8    9
```

---

Or use `outer`

```
outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(n)-1, `+`)
```

---

If we need a `for` loop

```
m1 <- matrix(0, n , n)
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    for(j in seq_len(n)) {
   
     m1[i, j] <- i +  (j - 1)
 }
}
```

-output

```
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    6
#[3,]    3    4    5    6    7
#[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
#[5,]    5    6    7    8    9
```

---

Or using a single `for` loop

```
m1 <- matrix(0, n , n)
s1 <- seq_len(n)

for(i in s1) m1[i,] <- s1 + (i-1)
```

---

Or another option with `embed`

```
embed(c(1:9, 1:9), n)[s1, rev(s1)]
```

Comment: thank you for solving my problem it's working but I need to use my algorithm this is my homework and I want to achieve the same result by using 1 for loop

Comment: thank you a lot you are perfect but I have a question for you can we solve this with 1 for loop is it possible?

Comment: @BarışBabahan it is possible, but then it becomes more vectorized and not completely a for loop

Comment: can you explain to me or show me how to do it with 1 for a loop because I need it

Comment: thank you a lot I appreciate for your effort

Comment: Here is a pure for loop way if you want @BarışBabahan: `n = 5L; m = matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n); for (k in 1:(n*n)) {i = (k-1) %% n + 1; j = (k-1) %/% n + 1; m[i,j] = i+j-1}`

Comment: @akrun, your answers are quite useful to other users, but I'm a little annoyed at the OP, who has posted what is presumably a homework question (why else would there be a constraint disallowing vectorized solutions ... ?), without any visible effort ... I downvoted, but that's all I can do ...

Comment: @BenBolker I do agree that it may be a homework.  When I first answered the question, I used `sapply` and `outer`.  Then the OP requested `for` loop solutions.  Sometimes, people are just curious to understand how a vectorized solution in `R` can be done in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Another quick way could be:

```
 x <- diag(5)
 row(x) + col(x) - 1
```